# Highlighting code block in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana, highlight

I am thinking about using Aptana Studio 3 but when it comes to nested HTML I really need code blocks highlighting and I have noticed that this feature is missing there.  [Here is example of code highlighting from Spring Tool Suite which is also made on Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DydHg.png).

Is there any way to turn it on? I've tried comparing both Aptana and STS properties but I couldn't find any differences.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not a feature. However, as you can see selecting a tag does highlight the closing tag, and if you hover over the line counts, a thin gray line will mark the boundaries of the current block.

[image]

Comment: It needs additional hovering and it's not as apparent as it's in STS but it's still better than nothing. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not what you are looking for but I believe it is as close as Aptana Studio 3 gets.